# Editing argv[1] if not entered by user C

Tags: c

Is it possible to get empty string in `argv[1]` if user doesn't input anything?
If user doesn't input `argv[1]`, I need to be able to work with it as it was empty string.

I tried assigning the empty string to `argv[1]` but it prints segmentation fault

Comment: Sounds like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/209820). Also, please [edit] and add your code.

Comment: Do you really need to  edit `argv`? You can check the value of `argc`, which contains the number of arguments (including the executable name). So, you can have an if statement that checks if `argc` is 1 (i.e., no arguments have been given by the user), in which case do the thing that you are requiring an empty string for.

Comment: Treat `argv[1]` as if it is immutable. Then `char *param = (argc == 2) ? argv[1] : "";` Done...

Answer (score 5):

You can use `argc` to know how many elements are in `argv` and respond accordingly.  The first value is the name of the program, all following values are user inputs.

```
int main(int argc, char * argv[]){
  
  char * str;

  if (argc < 2){
     // .... create your empty string
     str = "";
  } else {
     // .... assign argv[1] to your string
     str = argv[1];
  }
  // ... do stuff with string

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: This code is not about the question. The author said *Editing argv[1] if not entered by user C* not a,  e.g.,  substitute missing values by using another variable

Comment: @arfneto True your answer is more correct based on the question asked, but my approach will get the job done in far fewer lines.  As pointed out by 001, this is most likely an XY problem, so I answered what I thought the real issue is.  The answer by pmg is very clever, clean and probably the most useful...hence I upvoted that one.

Comment: :) I would not say that renaming `main` to `oldmain` and then create a minimum `main` and then change `argv` anyway is *clever* but certainly is possible. ;)

Answer (score 3):

CHEAT! your compiler will be happy

```
// rename your main as
int oldmain(int argc, char **argv) {
    // your code
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    if (argc == 1) {
        return oldmain(2, (char*[]){argv[0], "-----------------------", NULL});
    } else {
        return oldmain(argc, argv);
    }
}
```

Comment: What happened if you pass two or more arguments? It will not receive correct parameter list.

Comment: @winapiadmin: always pass 2 arguments to `main()` (or `oldmain()`): one integer and one pointer.

Comment: Plus the first param in oldmain is misspelled, causing a constraint violation so it doesn't even compile.

Comment: This code is not about the question. The question: *Editing argv[1] if not entered by user C* not,  e.g.,  substitute missing values by using another variable

Comment: @arfneto that all depends on how you define "editing", doesn't it?  I think this is quite clever and probably delivers exactly what the OP wants.

Comment: @MarkRansom :) I would not say that renaming `main` to `oldmain` and then create a minimum `main` and then change `argv` anyway is *clever* but certainly is possible and easy. ;)

Comment: @arfneto you could use a macro `#define main oldmain`, would that make it clever?

Comment: @MarkRansom macros can not make things clever, only obscure them. And there is no reason to mess up with `main` and `oldmain` much less introduce also a macro. Just fix `argv` and do not touch the program. See my answer and the one for @0_________

Answer (score 3):

Standard does not say about modifying the array of pointers referenced by `argv` (not `argv` itself and C strings referenced by elements of this array). You need to:

```
    char **newargv = malloc((argc + 2) * sizeof(*newargv));
    memcpy(newargv, argv, (argc) * sizeof(*newargv));
    newargv[argc] = "Hello";
    newargv[argc + 1] = NULL;
    argc++;
    argv = newargv;
```

Comment: Any comment sillemt DVter?

Comment: A missing `{` can clearly not justify a DV.

Comment: @EricPostpischil: argv (the local pointer in main()) and the strings pointed to by argv[0], argv[1], ... argv[argc-1] (i.e. the null-terminated arrays of char) are guaranteed modifiable; the argv elements argv[0], argv[1], ... argv[argc] themselves are not. In practice _implementations_ do allow modifications of the entries that exist (but not adding new ones).

Comment: @EricPostpischil There are 3 things which you can potentially change: `argv` itself, the pointer array referenced by the `argv`, and strings referenced by this array elements. 1st & and 3rd are mentioned in the standard. The 2nd is not mentioned in the Standard making it not specified behaviour.  *"Please check the standard before posting assertions about what it does or does not say"*

Comment: @0___________: You are correct; that was a deliberate omission by the C committee.

Comment: minimalist and rigth to the point! Great one.

Answer (score 1):

If the user doesn't enter anything then `argv[1]` doesn't exist, since `argc==1` in that case and `argv[1]` would be an access out of bounds.

What you can do instead is to create a working copy that fulfills your needs in case `argv` is empty. For example:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

#define ARGV_MIN 2

int main (int argc, char* argv[]) 
{
  char* argv_workcopy[argc > 1 ? argc : ARGV_MIN];
  argv_workcopy[1] = "";

  for(int i=0; i<argc; i++)
  {
    argv_workcopy[i] = argv[i];
  }

  // do something with the string:
  puts(argv_workcopy[1]);
}
```

In this case `argv_workcopy` is a variable-length array (VLA) of pointers, either as large as `argc` or in case there weren't any command line paraments, it will have size `2`.

Default values are entered as `argv_workcopy[1] = "";`. This is a read-only empty string, but note that you could as well let this point at read/write memory such as the memory returned by a `malloc` call.

If there are `argv` strings passed, they will overwrite the default. If not, the default will be used. So in case I call this program as `myprog hello world` then it will print `hello`, but if I call it as `myprog`, it will print an empty line.

(Also this program doesn't add a NULL sentinel at the end of `argv` so if you need that functionality, you need to increase `ARGV_MIN` and assign a NULL manually.)

Comment: C 2018 5.1.2.2.1 2: “… `argv[argc]` shall be a null pointer…”

Comment: @EricPostpischil Yep I know, hence the parenthesis at the end. The OP may or may not need that null pointer, but that's a separate issue.

Comment: This code is not about the question. The question: *Editing argv[1] if not entered by user C* not,  e.g.,  substitute missing values by using another variable. But it is a nice solution anyway

Answer (score 0):

It is a mission of the program loader to manage `argc` and `argv` at program start. But in a program were `main` is

```
    int main(int argc, char** argv);
```

These are as declared, an `int` and a `char**`. But `argc` could be `unsigned`, `argv`could be `char*[]`, or they could boh be declared `const`. It is just a function and its arguments. The *special things* occurs before and after program execution. So you can use it as you see fit.

Consider this

#### example

This is the output of the example (5 arguments were expected) for some arguments, no arguments or few arguments. Just for the example, missing arguments are generated and inserted as shown and `free`'d at exit.
The first argument is the program name, and the array `argv` ends with a `NULL` pointer, and this is preserved in the example code.
A new `argv` array is generated if needed and replaces the initial one so the program can go on without knowing if the arguments were or not provided in the command line.

#### output

```
C:\SO_  ./p 1 2 3 4 last
argument(s) ok    5 arguments on command line:
        #1:                        1
        #2:                        2
        #3:                        3
        #4:                        4
        #5:                     last
C:\SO_ 
C:\SO_  ./p
    5 argument (s) missing
    argv[1] created as "(Generated) argv[1]"
    argv[2] created as "(Generated) argv[2]"
    argv[3] created as "(Generated) argv[3]"
    argv[4] created as "(Generated) argv[4]"
    argv[5] created as "(Generated) argv[5]"
    5 arguments on command line:
        #1:      (Generated) argv[1]
        #2:      (Generated) argv[2]
        #3:      (Generated) argv[3]
        #4:      (Generated) argv[4]
        #5:      (Generated) argv[5]
    free argv[1]
    free argv[2]
    free argv[3]
    free argv[4]
    free argv[5]
C:\SO_  ./p arg1 arg2
    3 argument (s) missing
    argv[1] is present: "arg1"
    argv[2] is present: "arg2"
    argv[3] created as "(Generated) argv[3]"
    argv[4] created as "(Generated) argv[4]"
    argv[5] created as "(Generated) argv[5]"
    5 arguments on command line:
        #1:                     arg1
        #2:                     arg2
        #3:      (Generated) argv[3]
        #4:      (Generated) argv[4]
        #5:      (Generated) argv[5]
    free argv[3]
    free argv[4]
    free argv[5]
```

In general if you need to change these it is more convenient to just fix them instead of creating and using a new argument's array in the program. It can be just a fix in an older program so it is boring to go and change everywhere.

This function in the example prints the array of arguments, and do not care if they were tampered with:

```
int print_args(int argc, char** argv, const char* msg)
{
    if (msg != NULL) printf("%s", msg);
    printf("    %d arguments on command line:\n", argc-1);
    for (int i = 1; i < argc; i += 1)
        printf("\t#%d:\t%20s\n", i, argv[i]);
    return 0;
}
```

At the end of the program the generated arguments should be `free`'d, as good practice it is.

#### code for the example

```
#define EXPECTED 6

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int print_args(int argc, char** argv, const char*);

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    const char* prefix = "(Generated) argv[";
    // if there at least EXPECTED we are good to go
    if (argc == EXPECTED)
    {
        print_args(argc, argv, "argument(s) ok");
        return 0;
    }
    int missing = EXPECTED - argc;
    // missing at least 1
    printf("    %d argument (s) missing\n", missing);
    char** nd_argv = malloc((1 + EXPECTED) * sizeof(char*));
    nd_argv[0]     = argv[0];  // the program name
    nd_argv[EXPECTED] = NULL;  // the sentinel pointer
    for (int i = 1; i < EXPECTED; i += 1)
    {
        if (i < argc)
        {
            printf(
                "    argv[%d] is present: \"%s\"\n", i,
                argv[i]);
            nd_argv[i] = argv[i];
            continue;
        }
        char* one_arg = malloc(strlen(prefix) + 3);
        sprintf(one_arg, "%s%d]", prefix, i);
        printf(
            "    argv[%d] created as \"%s\"\n", i, one_arg);
        nd_argv[i] = one_arg;
    }
    argc = EXPECTED;
    argv = nd_argv;
    print_args(argc, argv, NULL);
    for (int i = argc - missing; i < argc; i += 1)
    {
        printf("    free argv[%d]\n", i);
        free(argv[i]);
    }
    free(argv[EXPECTED]);  // free the sentinel
    free(nd_argv);         // and the array itself
    return 0;
}

int print_args(int argc, char** argv, const char* msg)
{
    if (msg != NULL) printf("%s", msg);
    printf("    %d arguments on command line:\n", argc - 1);
    for (int i = 1; i < argc; i += 1)
        printf("\t#%d:\t%20s\n", i, argv[i]);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: There is a well hidden potential bug if `EXPECTED` is changed to a value greater than `9`.  Also `argc` should not be defined as `unsigned` in the `main` prototype, but *`int` can be replaced by a typedef name defined as `int`*

Comment: This is just an example to show that is possible, and a way to create and destroy missing arguments at the end of `argv`. And yes, I did not checked for the return of `malloc`, as others pointed at. And you are right @chqrlie the use of the `prefix` thing and the magic `3` may turn to a problem.

Answer (score 0):

Revoking my previous answer(s), in this silly quest, a simple solution that, I believe, has not been suggested yet, yet answers specifically the OP's desire to have `argv[1]` set to a default value when not supplied on the command line.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main( int argc, char *argv[] ) {
    if( argc == 1 ) {
        char arg1[] = "argument #1"; // mutable!!
        char *argvX[] = {
            argv[0],
            arg1,
            NULL,
        };
        return main( 2, argvX ); // RECURSION!!!
    }

    // Note the use of 'argc' and 'argv' as requested.
    for( int i = 0; i <= argc; i++ ) 
        printf( "[%d] \"%s\"\n", i, argv[i] );

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
[0] "demo"
[1] "argument #1"
[2] "(null)"   // printf() can be kind, printing a NULL ptr
```

No `malloc/free` worries. No VLAs. Portable. Extensible. KISS...

Answer (score 0):

The C Standard has quite a few rules governing `argc` and `argv`.
See [C11 5.1.2.2.1p2](https://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#5.1.2.2.1p2)

> - `argv[argc]` shall be a null pointer.
> - [...]
> - The parameters `argc` and `argv` and the strings pointed to by the `argv` array shall be modifiable by the program, and retain their last-stored values between program startup and program termination.

So, in your situation of `argc == 1`, you may change the `NULL` to something else:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    if (argc == 1) {
        argv[1] = malloc(7);
        if (!argv[1]) exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        strcpy(argv[1], "foobar");
    }

    // rest of code that keeps `argc` unchanged
    // also do not pass argc and argv to some code
    //     that reasonably expects argv[argc] to be NULL

    if (argc == 1) {
        free(argv[1]);
        // return to the initial situation in case the library code needs it
        argv[1] = NULL;
    }
}
```

Note that `argv[2]` does not exist in this situation. You cannot change that.
Also note that while `argv[0]` is a plain old regular string (ar any other `argv` element), you don't know the size of the underlying array, except that it's at least `strlen(argv[0]) + 1`. If you are going to change it, refrain to make it larger than the initial strlen

```
size_t len0 = strlen(argv[0]);
argv[0][len0] = 'X'; // argv[0] is no longer a string
argv[0][len0+1] = 0; // possible UB: that byte may not belong to the array
```

Comment: Sorry, but... Since this code is _hoodwinking_ `argv[1]`, it really should increment `argc` to `2` to be correct for "rest of code"... Might need some more thought... `:-)`

Comment: Thing is `argv[2]` does not exist... and there's no way to create it (other than making a whole new complete `argv` from scratch). I still like my other answer best :-)

Comment: "_argv[2] does not exist..._" That's the crux of the issue... Read the comments under the OP's question, the other answers and the discussion there, too... This _almost_ answer doesn't need dynamic memory. Simply `char foo[] = "foobar"; argv[1] = foo;` would do it without the `free()` confusion at the end.

Comment: *The parameters argc and argv and the strings pointed to by the argv array shall be modifiable by the program,*  says nothing about changing the existing elements of the array `argv` initially points to.  This omission might not be intentional but the Standard text for this has not been modified since ANSI-C, so we should not modify the argument array.

Answer (score 0):

If the user did not type anything as a command line argument after the name of the program, the `main` function receives `argc` with a value of `1` and `argv` points to an array of 2 `char *`, the first may point to a string with the program name and the second is a null pointer, not an empty string.

If you attempt to overwrite the missing argument in `argv[1]` with `strcpy(argv[1], "default")`, you definitely invoke undefined behavior as `argv[1]` is a null pointer and it is a good explanation for the segmentation fault you observe.

The C Standard specifies in **5.1.2.2.1 Program startup** that

> **5.1.2.2.1 Program startup**
>
> 1    The function called at program startup is named `main`. The implementation declares no prototype for this function. It shall be defined with a return type of `int` and with no parameters:
>
> ```
>   int main(void) { /* ... */ }
> ```
>
> or with two parameters (referred to here as `argc` and `argv`, though any names may be used, as they are local to the function in which they are declared):
>
> ```
>  int main(int argc, char *argv[]) { /* ... */ }
> ```
>
> or equivalent or in some other implementation-defined manner.
>
> 2    If they are declared, the parameters to the `main` function shall obey the following constraints:
> — The value of `argc` shall be non negative.
> — `argv[argc]` shall be a null pointer.
> — If the value of `argc` is greater than zero, the array members `argv[0]` through `argv[argc-1]` inclusive shall contain pointers to strings, which are given implementation-defined values by the host environment prior to program startup. The intent is to supply to the program information determined prior to program startup from elsewhere in the hosted environment. If the host environment is not capable of supplying strings with letters in both uppercase and lowercase, the implementation shall ensure that the strings are received in lowercase.
> — If the value of `argc` is greater than zero, the string pointed to by `argv[0]` represents the program name; `argv[0][0]` shall be the null character if the program name is not available from the host environment. If the value of `argc` is greater than one, the strings pointed to by `argv[1]` through `argv[argc-1]` represent the program parameters.
> — The parameters `argc` and `argv` and the strings pointed to by the `argv` array shall be modifiable by the program, and retain their last-stored values between program startup and program termination.

Hence you should not attempt to modify `argv[1]` to make it point the missing argument value as `argv[1] = "default"`, although this might work as expected on most targets. Instead, you can modify the `argv` argument itself to make it point to another array with the proper contents:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    char *new_args[3];
    
    if (argc < 2) {
        new_args[0] = argv[0];
        new_args[1] = "world";
        new_args[2] = NULL;
        argv = new_argv;
        argc = 2;
    }
    printf("Hello %s\n", argv[1]);
    return 0;
}
```

This method is somewhat non conventional: a more classic approach uses named variables with default values for optional command line arguments:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    char *name = "world";
    
    if (argc > 1) {
        name = argv[1];
    }
    printf("Hello %s\n", name);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You will get segfault caused by index out of bounds exception

For parsing args in C you should checkout getopt and argp:

- http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Getopt.html
- http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Argp.html

Comment: I don't know about the index out of bounds error, since `argv` always ends with a `NULL` pointer at `argv[argc]`.

Comment: And that's why. You're using `argv[1]` but you're saying "since `argv` always ends with a `NULL` pointer at `argv[argc]`", and `argc` resolves to 1.

Comment: @winapiadmin `argc` does not count the `NULL` pointer at the end. From [cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/main_function): _argv - Pointer to the first element of an array of **argc + 1** pointers, of which the last one is null_ (Emphasis mine).

Comment: @001 If you increment `argc` to 2 and store another value in `argv[1]` you must also add the new `NULL` terminator in `argv[2]` which does not exist.

Comment: @Gerhardh I don't know if you _must_ add the `NULL`, unless other code in your program is expecting it. But that has nothing to do with my original point, which is accessing `argv[argc]` is not  an out of bounds error.

Comment: You already write yourself: `argv` always ends with a `NULL` pointer. How would anyone be able to know that this is not true for them because someone messed up with the counter?

Comment: @Gerhardh OK, if I worked for you, you could fire me for writing to `argv[argc]`. But, _none of that has anything to do with my original comment_. Which is that the first line of the answer is misleading. Besides the fact that C does not have exceptions, you won't get a segfault for writing to `argv[argc]`. That's all.

Comment: @Gerhardh: The rule in the C standard is that `argv` always ends in a null pointer when the program starts in a hosted environment. There is no rule precluding the program from changing it after it starts. It is up to the author whether or not anything else in their program relies on that.

Comment: This has no relation to the question. `getopt()` adds nothing here. segfault was due to an error in code, not to the use (reuse) of `argv` or `argc`. Both were not declared `const` and rarely are anyway. Both are normal variables.